# Find the solution to the initial value problem $\overline{x}' = A\overline{x}, x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}{2} \\ {28}\end{bmatrix} $

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$A = \begin{bmatrix}{16/3} && {1/3} \\ {-64/3} && {32/3}\end{bmatrix} $

I got the general solution $\overline{x} = c_1 e^{8t} \begin{bmatrix}{1} \\ {8}\end{bmatrix} + c_2 (te^{8t}\begin{bmatrix}{1} \\ {8}\end{bmatrix}+e^{8t} \begin{bmatrix}{0} \\ {3}\end{bmatrix})$, which with the initial conditions gave $\overline{x} = 2 e^{8t} \begin{bmatrix}{1} \\ {8}\end{bmatrix} + \frac{20}{3} (te^{8t}\begin{bmatrix}{1} \\ {8}\end{bmatrix}+e^{8t} \begin{bmatrix}{0} \\ {3}\end{bmatrix})$.

Apparently this solution is wrong and I am unsure why. If someone can point out any errors I made/show me the correct answer, that would be fantastic. Thanks.

I was also unable to check my answer on wolfram alpha because I don't know the right syntax to use. Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you plug $t=0$ into your solution, you get $\overline x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}{2} \\ {36}\end{bmatrix}$, so it is not correct.  As you did not show the solution, we can't find the error.  If you just type eigenvalues into the box in [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues&a=*C.eigenvalues-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%7B%7B16%2F3%2C1%2F3%7D%2C%7B-64%2F3%2C32%2F3%7D%7D&f=Eigenvalue.eigvalmatrix_%7B%7B16%2F3%2C1%2F3%7D%2C%7B-64%2F3%2C32%2F3%7D%7D) it gives you a box below with a sample matrix that shows the format.  It agrees with your double eigenvalue of $8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\overline x = \begin{bmatrix}{x_1} \\ {x_2}\end{bmatrix}.$$ We have system of equations :
$$x'_1=\frac{16}{3} x_1 + \frac{1}{3} x_2, $$
$$x'_2=-\frac{64}{3} x_1 + \frac{32}{3} x_2, $$
$$x_1(0)=2,$$
$$x_2(0)=28.$$
From the first equation we have $x_2=3x'_1-16x_2$. After substitution into the second equation:
$$9x''_1-144x'_1+576=0,$$ 
since the characteristic equation is $(3t-24)^2=0$,

we have $x_1=e^{8t}(C_1t+C_2)$ and $x_2=e^{8t}(3C_1+8C_2+8C_1t)$.

It is easy to calculate $C_1$ and $C_2$ from conditions $x_1(0)=2$ and $x_2(0)=28$; we have $C_1=4$ and $C_2=2$.

Finally,
$$x_1=e^{8t}(4t+2),$$ $$x_2=e^{8t}(28+32t).$$